# Foreign currency signs in XeTeX

Tags: xetex, unicode

I'm creating an invoice document using LaTeX that is supposed to have any currency symbol in the document. However, when converting to PDF, the signs never show up, most likely because I'm not using the correct packages. Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Do I need to install a list of packages and fonts in order to use these characters in my document? The document is created in Python and the currency signs are grabbed from a hash table. I'm on a Linux machine if that matters.

Say if I just wanted a document to print these characters, how would I accomplish that? Is there a font or package that contains all of these?:

ден
₪
₹
ع.د
₲
฿
₩
¥
؋

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx! Which font(s) are you using for your typesetting?

Comment: Whatever the default font is.

Comment: search **currency** in [this list](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/)

Comment: There were no results. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a font that supplies the glyphs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O} % or whatever
\newfontfamily{\currencies}{FreeSerif}[Scale=MatchUppercase]

\begin{document}

{\currencies ден ₪ ₹ ع.د ₲ ฿ ₩ ¥ ؋}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different approach (but just for single glyphs) that takes the glyph from the current font, if it exists, or from the fall back `\currencies`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O} % or whatever
\newfontfamily{\currencies}{FreeSerif}[Scale=MatchUppercase]

\newcommand{\curr}[1]{%
  {\iffontchar\font`#1 #1\else\currencies#1\fi}%
}

\begin{document}

\curr{₪}
\curr{₹}
\curr{¥}
\curr{₩}
\curr{฿}
\curr{₲}
\curr{؋}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may even avoid using `\curr` by loading `newunicodechar`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O} % or whatever
\newfontfamily{\currencies}{FreeSerif}[Scale=MatchUppercase]

\newcommand{\curr}[1]{%
  {\iffontchar\font`#1 #1\else\currencies#1\fi}%
}
\newunicodechar{₪}{\curr{₪}}
\newunicodechar{₹}{\curr{₹}}
\newunicodechar{¥}{\curr{¥}}
\newunicodechar{₩}{\curr{₩}}
\newunicodechar{฿}{\curr{฿}}
\newunicodechar{₲}{\curr{₲}}
\newunicodechar{؋}{\curr{؋}}

\begin{document}

₪ ₹ ¥ ₩ ฿ ₲ ؋

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll try this out!

Answer (score 4):

Since you compile with `XeLaTeX`, you have a number of currency symbols in the font `fontawesome`. The package `fontawesome` helps using this font, unfortunately it defines commands for version 3.1  of the fonts, which had no currency symbols.

You can download the latest version (`4.3`) of the fonts [here](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) and use the preamble of the following code; which defiines commands and some aliases to use them in a .tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\makeatletter
\expandafter\def\csname faicon@mobile\endcsname {\symbol{"F10B}} \def\faMobile {{\FA\csname faicon@mobile\endcsname}}
\expandafter\def\csname faicon@eur\endcsname {\symbol{"F153}} \def\faEur {{\FA\csname faicon@eur\endcsname}}
\expandafter\def\csname faicon@gbp\endcsname {\symbol{"F154}} \def\faGbp {{\FA\csname faicon@gbp\endcsname}}
\expandafter\def\csname faicon@usd\endcsname {\symbol{"F155}} \def\faUsd {{\FA\csname faicon@usd\endcsname}}
\expandafter\def\csname faicon@inr\endcsname {\symbol{"F156}} \def\faInr {{\FA\csname faicon@inr\endcsname}}
\expandafter\def\csname faicon@jpy\endcsname {\symbol{"F157}} \def\faJpy {{\FA\csname faicon@jpy\endcsname}}
\expandafter\def\csname faicon@rub\endcsname {\symbol{"F158}} \def\faRub {{\FA\csname faicon@rub\endcsname}}
\expandafter\def\csname faicon@krw\endcsname {\symbol{"F159}} \def\faKrw {{\FA\csname faicon@krw\endcsname}}
\expandafter\def\csname faicon@btc\endcsname {\symbol{"F15A}} \def\faBtc {{\FA\csname faicon@btc\endcsname}}
\expandafter\def\csname faicon@try\endcsname {\symbol{"F195}} \def\faTry {{\FA\csname faicon@try\endcsname}}
\expandafter\def\csname faicon@ils\endcsname {\symbol{"F20B}} \def\faIls {{\FA\csname faicon@ils\endcsname}}

%%Aliases
\expandafter\def\csname faicon@bitcoin\endcsname {\faBitcoin} \def\faBitcoin {\faBtc}
\expandafter\def\csname faicon@dollar\endcsname {\faDollar} \def\faDollar {\faUsd}
\expandafter\def\csname faicon@euro\endcsname {\faEuro} \def\faEuro {\faEur}
\expandafter\def\csname faicon@ruble\endcsname {\faRuble} \def\faRuble {\faRub}
\expandafter\def\csname faicon@rupee\endcsname {\faRupee} \def\faRupee {\faInr}
\expandafter\def\csname faicon@shekel\endcsname {\faShekel} \def\faShekel {\faIls}
\expandafter\def\csname faicon@sheqel\endcsname {\faSheqel} \def\faSheqel {\faIls}
\expandafter\def\csname faicon@turkish-lira\endcsname {\faTurkishLira} \def\faTurkishLira {\faTry}
\expandafter\def\csname faicon@won\endcsname {\faWon} \def\faWon {\faKrw}
\expandafter\def\csname faicon@yen\endcsname {\faYen} \def\faYen {\faJpy}

\makeatother

    \begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    \Huge

    \fontspec{fontawesome.otf}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\color{Turquoise1}}c >{\color{HotPink3}} c >{\color{DarkSeaGreen2}}c }
    \toprule
 \faEur& \faGbp & \faUsd\\
 \faRupee & \faYen & \faRuble \\
 \faWon & \faShekel & \faTurkishLira \\
  & \faBtc\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: According to http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/#currency, they barely have any icons for currency.

Comment: They have the ten I showed. Of course, if you need more, you can ask them to design them in a later version…

Comment: No Tomato here? :(

Comment: Hi, Manuel! :o)