# Cedi ₵ symbol in LaTeX

Tags: symbols

How can one include the Cedi symbol ₵ in a LaTeX document? More about this currency symbol can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghanaian_cedi

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/226343/253465) answer.

Comment: Do you mean `cent` symbol, if yes, try with `\usepackage{wasysym}` and the tag is `\cent`

Comment: @MadyYuvi it is actually a distinquished Unicode character, U+20b5 CEDI SIGN

Comment: @Jaap Thanks
`\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O} % or whatever
\newfontfamily{\currencies}{FreeSerif}[Scale=MatchUppercase]

\newcommand{\curr}[1]{%
  {\iffontchar\font\`#1 #1\else\currencies#1\fi}%
}

\begin{document}
\curr{₵}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 4):

In addendum to the comments I can suggest to use `textcomp` package that provide to get the desidered symbols without to touch the CM font (default) symbols:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
In text mode
\textcent, \textcentoldstyle, \textcolonmonetary,

In math mode

$\mbox{\textcent}, \mbox{\textcentoldstyle}, \mbox{\textcolonmonetary}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As of 2021, the `textcomp` package has been integrated into the kernel, making `\usepackage{textcomp}` redundant. (But harmless.) Older installations might still need it, though.

Comment: Very kind  
Davislor I have not understood the assert textcomp package has been integrated into the kernel! What is the real reason? Thank you very much.-

Comment: You’d can ask the LaTeX kernel maintainers what their reasoning was, but here’s my guess. Back in the ’90s, people often bought Type 1 fonts and wanted to convert them to LaTeX encodings. These fonts used different 8-bit encodings from TeX, and typically would support some but not all of the symbols in TS1. The original purpose of creating `\usepackage{textcomp}` instead of `\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}` was to attempt to detect which symbols your Type 1 font actually had. In this century,  nobody does that any more. It’s more important that those symbols support `fontspec`.